# Interval timer click

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

How do i get my winforms app to click the button on the form based on an interval which is defined in a text box on my form?

I have tried:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer tm;
    tm = new Timer();
    tm.Interval = 1000;
    tm.Tick += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
}
```

Once the timer starts and they click Yes to the dialog box, then i want the timer to restart again.

I have the following:

```
 if (result1 == DialogResult.Yes)
   {
       string pastebuffer = DateTime.Now.ToString();
       pastebuffer = "### Edited on " + pastebuffer + " by " + txtUsername.Text + "###"; 
       Clipboard.SetText(pastebuffer);
   }
   else if (result1 == DialogResult.No)
   {
       //do something else
   }
```

Comment: Dialog box??  Form1 does not sound like a great name for a dialog class.

Answer (score 1):

To stop the timer, use

```
tm.Stop();
```

Then you can change whatever the interval is, or any other properties as such

```
tm.Interval = int.Parse(textBox1.Text); // Will fail on non-int input...
```

then use,

```
tm.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add interval from textBox and start the timer, all from a click of a button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  timer1.Stop(); // if you need to stop, then stop it here
  timer1.Interval = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
  timer1.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code. Hope it will help. Define **Time tm** on *class level* so that you can access outside the Form1_load function.

```
Timer tm;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tm = new Timer();
        tm.Interval = 1000;
        tm.Tick += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
    }




    if (result1 == DialogResult.Yes)
    {

      'if you want to restart your timer than add here.
      tm.stop()
      tm.Interval = int.Parse(newinterval.text);
      string pastebuffer = DateTime.Now.ToString();
      pastebuffer = "### Edited on " + pastebuffer + " by " + txtUsername.Text + "###"; 
      Clipboard.SetText(pastebuffer);
      tm.start()
   }
   else if (result1 == DialogResult.No)
   {
         //do something else
   }
```